# Prove function is continuous given LHS and RHD limits converge to same value.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove of disprove: If $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfies $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x+h)-f(x-h) = 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$, then $f$ is continuous.

Is this proof correct? I was trying to show f is differentiable $\forall x$, which would imply f is continuous, but ended up with this (almost too simple to be true) proof.

Pick arbitrary $x_0 \in \mathbb R$. $$lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0 - h) = 0 \rightarrow lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x_0 + h) = lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x_0 - h)$$

This implies (Is this too much of a jump?)$$lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+} f(x) = lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-} f(x)$$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ (Is this too much of a jump? Should I use $\epsilon -\delta$ to be more rigorous?) . Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, this is true $\forall x$, and thus $f$ is continuous.

Comment: No,your argument is not correct. You are not given that the  left and right  limits exist at every point.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)=1$ for $ x \neq 0$ and $0 $ for $x=0$ then the hypothesis is satisfied but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: oof.. ok. Would I have to prove by showing f is differentiable at every point, which implies f is cont?

Comment: If you need to prove that a function is continuous, is not usual try to prove that $f$ is differentiable. In fact, $f$ differentiable implies $f$ continuous, but $f$ can be continuous and not be differentiable.

Comment: @MinYoungKim My example shows that $f$ need not be continuous. So where is the question of discussing differentiabilty?

Comment: Oh, I'm so dumb. It's prove or disprove. Thank you.